# Si può usare "forma" come sinonimo di "modo"?

Tags: word-usage

Cercando la parola ["forma"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/forma/) nel vocabolario Treccani, ho trovato questa accezione:

> **3.** In senso più astratto, modo di essere, di presentarsi; così, con riferimento alla struttura, all’ordinamento, alla costituzione politica, si parla di *forme di governo*, di *f. monarchica, repubblicana*, ecc.; in economia, *forma di mercato*, configurazione, regime, struttura di mercato. In medicina, e nel linguaggio com., il modo con cui determinate malattie insorgono e si sviluppano: *f. atipiche, infettive, f. benigne o maligne, f. lievi o gravi*. In altre espressioni equivale spesso a genere, qualità: *inventare nuove f. d’arte, di spettacolo, di divertimenti; quanto tempo ha che tu sei ridotto a cotesta f. di vita?* (Leopardi). In altre ancora, si riferisce piuttosto al modo con cui un’azione è fatta: *celebrare, commemorare in f. solenne; assistere, partecipare a una cerimonia in f. privata*.

La mia domanda è: fino a che punto si può usare il vocabolo "forma" in questo senso come sinonimo di "modo"? Per esempio, ecco il titolo di una mia domanda:

> Diversi *modi* di tradurre “in such a way that” in italiano.

Sarebbe corretto sostituire qui "diversi modi" con "diverse forme" per ottenere questa frase?

> Diverse *forme* di tradurre “in such a way that” in italiano.

Comment: Al limite, ma suonerebbe un po' legnoso, “Diverse forme di traduzione dell'espressione ‘in such a way that’”...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentre spesso si può sostituire tranquillamente "modo" con "forma" (aggiustando le concordanze), ci sono alcuni casi in cui è sbagliato:

- Nell'espressione "a modo mio"
- Nella domanda "in che modo?"
- Nell'espressione "in modo da"
- Quando è accompagnato da un aggettivo con funzione di complemento di modo ("in modo alacre")
- Più in generale, è necessario utilizzare "modo" rispetto a "forma" quando è riferito ad un'azione. Ad esempio: "in che modo cucini la pasta?"

Comment: Dunque, in modo simile all'ultimo esempio, la frase «diverse forme di tradurre “in such a way that" in italiano» non sarebbe corretta, no?

Comment: @Charo esattamente :)