# Cosa significa esprimersi in modo legnoso?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives

Il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/legnoso/) menziona questo uso figurato del termine "legnoso":

> *stile legnoso*, secco, eccessivamente stringato.

Questo vocabolo però l'ho visto usato per la prima volta per descrivere il modo di esprimersi in [questo commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/si-pu%c3%b2-usare-forma-come-sinonimo-di-modo#comment7896_5410): «...suonerebbe un po' *legnoso*, ...». Penso che in questo caso il significato sia diverso di quello spiegato dal Treccani. È così? Potreste spiegarmi le diverse sfumature dell'aggettivo "legnoso" usato per descrivere il modo di esprimersi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il “colpevole” del commento era il sottoscritto. Lì usavo “legnoso” nel senso che il Treccani (nella stessa voce citata nella domanda ma riferendolo solo alla persona e ai suoi movimenti) parafrasa come «che manca di grazia, o di scioltezza, di agilità, rigido, impacciato». Anche lo Zanichelli dà, tra i significati figurati di “legnoso”, «privo di scioltezza, morbidezza, elasticità, disinvoltura e sim.»

Cercando un po' a casaccio qualche esempio di questo uso (evitando la ricca messe di usi più letterali dell'aggettivo), trovo tra gli altri:

> Nei film esaminati, gli elementi discorsivi vengono affrontati con una tecnica mista, che mostra quanto sia difficile trasferirli adeguatamente in tedesco. Succede che questi elementi vengono tralasciati sistematicamente, e la loro omissione, insieme ad altri aspetti della sintassi e del lessico, fa sì che **un personaggio che nella versione originale parlava in modo naturale e informale diventi invece formale e legnoso**, si veda ad esempio il capostazione nel film La Stazione / Der Bahnhof.
> (Da un [articolo sul doppiaggio in tedesco](http://www.intralinea.org/archive/article/Quanto_e_tedesco_Mimi_Metallurgico).)
>
> Anche chi usa termini che appartengono al **modo di esprimersi tendenzialmente involuto e legnoso della lingua in uso oggi**, dal poco simpatico taglio "sociologico", per così dire, lo fa sempre nell'ambito della "buona battaglia" per la difesa della vera fede, che ognuno combatte con i mezzi di cui è capace, tutti buoni e tutti validi.
> (Da [una discussione sulla Chiesa](http://chiesaepostconcilio.blogspot.it/2015/03/il-cardinal-muller-gettare-le.html), che ha preso una deriva linguistica.)

E anche quando, parlando dello stile di chi scriva in una lingua che non gli è del tutto congeniale, [qualcuno commenta](http://ilmiolibro.kataweb.it/booknews_dettaglio_news.asp?tipoord=news&id_contenuto=3763911) «quello che ieri era un'eccezione (dall'inglese travolgente del polacco Joseph Conrad allo stile legnoso di Italo Svevo che, ci hanno insegnato a scuola, in tedesco avrebbe scritto più fluidamente, ma ha deciso di essere italiano nello pseudonimo e nella lingua), oggi è una scelta piuttosto comune», direi proprio che – condivisibile o meno che sia il discorso – usi “legnoso” nel senso di “rigido e privo di scioltezza” e non in quello di “secco e stringato”.

Comment: Al di là dell'accezione che hai correttamente spiegato, quando sento usare l'aggettivo "legnoso" in senso figurato, mi viene in mente la situazione in cui uno si trova mangiando carote ... *legnose*... appunto, ossia "difficili da masticare e da mandare giù" :-)